# Why is the following if statement excluding an array that's identical to the rest?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have the following array of arrays:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', '"one"' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', '"two"' ],
  [ 'para', '"three"' ] ]
```

I made a loop to only match those arrays with double quotes:

```
for (i = 1; i < jsonml.length; i++) {

      if (typeof jsonml[i][1] === "string" && jsonml[i][1].match(/"/g)) {
        var p = jsonml[i]
        console.log(p)
      }

      // more code

      if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
        var hr = jsonml[i]
        var p = jsonml[i + 1]

        hr.splice(0, 1, 'para', '* * *')
        p.splice(1, 0, {'class': 'noind'})
      }
```

For some reason `console.log(p)` only outputs:

```
[ 'para', '"one"' ]
[ 'para', '"three"' ]
```

Is `[ 'hr' ]` somehow making `[ 'para', '"two"' ]` not to match the if statement? If so how to fix it so that `[ 'para', '"two"' ]` is matched, too?

```
 if (jsonml[i][0] === 'hr') {
    var hr = jsonml[i]
    var p = jsonml[i + 1]

    hr.splice(0, 1, 'para', '* * *')
    p.splice(1, 0, {'class': 'noind'})
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is with the if statement below, since `console.log(jsonml[i][1])` outputs:

```
"one"
undefined
{ class: 'noind' }
"three"
```

I thought the if statements would execute in order?

Comment: It does output all three matching items: http://jsfiddle.net/uL03nwwu/

Comment: @kamituel Please see my edit. I think the second if statement is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be because you are modifying the array while you are still iterating over it. Which means that the `[ 'para', '"two"' ]` item is no longer there by the time you get round to it.

Usually, you should always avoid modifying a collection while you are looping over it. If you need to make changes then do them either before or afterwards (which can also be using a separate loop if you need to)

Comment: He's not actually removing anything from the `jsonml` array. But he's modifying the row after `hr`, which is removing the string with quotes.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, I have seen the edit... I will adjust my answer

Comment: @musefan could you provide an example code of how I  can fix this?

Comment: @alexchenco: I can, but what do you actually want to happen? You are changing the item so it is expected it won't output. Do you mean to change it? Give an example of the full end result you are expecting